# how to display json data using const list

Tags: php, json, react-native, mysqli

how to display json data over fire in but how to call it using (const list =) example like this

```html
const list = [
{
id: 1,
name: 'June 1, 2018 - June 3, 2018',
avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uif…/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
subtitle: 'Sick Leave 3 Days',
image_status: require('../../assets/icon_double_check_gray.png')
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'July 7, 2018 - August 3, 2018',
avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/…/fa…/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
subtitle: 'Meeting Leave 9 Days',
image_status: require('../../assets/icon_double_check_green.png')
},
]
```

Comment: apart from that not beeing valid json (a `,` too much), where exactly is the problem?

Comment: and the image_status has no valid value

Comment: @Jeff I want to show json but after const list = using api

Comment: "show json" means what? echo it in php, in js? where is the json defined? possible answers span from `echo "const list =".$json` over `alert JSON.stringify(json);` to whatever... It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Hard time understanding your question. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Please mention the language, you want it in php or in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

in react native , you can use javascript methods and in your case , for working with Json , you can use this 2 methods

```
 JSON.stringify(yourJsonData)
```

or use

```
JSON.parse(yourJson)
```

if you are new in javascript and you dont know this methos

JSON.Parse() => this methods get String with JSON fromat ( for example you get this string from server or read from Database ) and translate Your string to Real JSON script

JSON.stringify() => this method like previous but reversed , for example you have JSON data and you want send this JSON data to server as String , this method Traslate your Json Format type to String for saving in database or used for GET or POS request

Answer (score 0):

if you means , you want show JSON in your ReactNative View , you must know this  ( any Object Or Array must use inside loop function  )

for example if you want show your JSON ,

```
class App extends React.Component
  {
     render() {

     return(

      <View>

      { list.map( (data) => (

        <Text> { data.id } </Text>
        <Text> { data.name } </Text>
        <Text> { data.subtitle } </Text>


      ))}

      </View>    

      )


     }

  }
```